# Terraform "Catch-22": Lack of unnecessary default AWS provider causes error; defining default provider breaks explicit per-region providers

Tags: terraform

***([Cross-posted to Terraform Discuss](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/terraform-catch-22-lack-of-default-provider-causes-error-default-provider-breaks-per-region-providers/62078) for better reach.)***

## I have a Catch-22 situation with Terraform:

1. If I don't define a default AWS provider (that I don't actually need) I get errors about the default provider not being defined
2. If I then define a default AWS provider, it breaks the use of the default AWS provider in modules, that have been overridden with aliased region-specific providers as they are passed in to the module

## Versions

The problems happen with both of these Terraform versions:

```
Terraform v1.7.1
on darwin_arm64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v5.31.0
```

```
Terraform v1.6.0
on darwin_arm64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v5.31.0
```

## Scenarios

*(All instances of `<AWS_REGION>` are actually replaced with a real AWS region identifier, such as `us-east-1` or otherwise.)*

### Scenario #1: No default AWS provider specified:

**Terraform configuration:**

```
# ./terraform.tf
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 5.31.0"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 1.6.0"
}
```

**There are several per-AWS-region aliased AWS providers defined in the root module**

```
provider "aws" {
  alias = "<AWS_REGION>"
  region = "<AWS_REGION>"
}

# Note: There is no default AWS provider, only aliased ones
```

**There are also several per-AWS-region modules with an overridden AWS provider passed in:**

```
# ./modules.tf
module "provider_<AWS_REGION>" {
  source    = "./<AWS_REGION>"

  # AWS per-region provider is passed in to the module, replacing its default provider
  providers = {
    aws = aws.<AWS_REGION>
  }
}
```

**Each module has all of the per-AWS-region configuration, here is an example:**

```
# Should use the default AWS provider `aws`, which has been replaced 

# ./<AWS_REGION>/vpc.tf
resource "aws_vpc" "name_of_vpc" {
  # (configuration)
}
```

**The local Terraform state has `module` and `provider` specified:**

```json
# ./terraform.tfstate
{
  "version": 4,
  "terraform_version": "1.7.0",
  "serial": 1459,
  "lineage": "<SOME_GUID>",
  "outputs": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "module": "module.provider_<AWS_REGION>",
      "mode": "managed",
      "type": "<TERRAFORM_RESOURCE_TYPE>",
      "name": "<TERRAFORM_RESOURCE_NAME>",
      "provider": "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"]",
      # ...
}
```

When running `terraform plan` (after a clean `init`), the following errors are emitted:

### Error: When no default provider is specified:

(When this doesn't exist: `provider "aws" { region = "<REGION>" }`)

```
│ Error: Invalid provider configuration
│
│ Provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws" requires explicit configuration. Add a provider block to the root module and
│ configure the provider's required arguments as described in the provider documentation.

╷
│ Error: Invalid AWS Region:
│
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
│   on <empty> line 0:
│   (source code not available)
```

### Scenario #2: Default provider is added:

**This default provider is added:**

```
./provider.tf
provider "aws" {
  region = "<ARBITRARY_AWS_REGION>"
}
```

**Result:**

There are no actual errors, but each region-specific module just thinks its AWS provider is for the arbitrary AWS region of the default AWS provider, when it seems like it should actually be whatever AWS-region-specific provider has been passed in to the module.

### Scenario #3: Adding `.<AWS_REGION>` to the end of the `provider` value in `terraform.tfstate`:

This error is emitted:

```
│                                                                                                                              │ To work with
│ module.provider_<AWS_REGION>.<TERRAFORM_RESOURCE_TYPE>.<TERRAFORM_RESOURCE_NAME>                                                                                                                   │ its original provider configuration at module.provider_us-east-1.provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"].<AWS_REGION>
│ is required, but it has been removed. This occurs when a provider configuration is removed while objects created by that     
│ provider still exist in the state. Re-add the provider configuration to destroy                                             
│ module.provider_us-east-1.<AWS_REGION>.<TERRAFORM_RESOURCE_TYPE>.<TERRAFORM_RESOURCE_NAME>,                                                                                                                  │ after which you can remove the provider configuration again.
```

### Scenario #4: Manually specifying `provider = aws.<AWS_REGION>` to the body of every resource in the AWS-region-specific modules

Doesn't help: It emits the `Error: Provider configuration not present` error.

### Scenario #5: Combining Scenario #3 and #4

Doesn't help: It emits the `Error: Provider configuration not present` error.

Comment: Is there a provider defined in the child module? Are you using the `configuration_alias` in the provider definition in the child module?

Comment: There are no providers defined in any child modules, all providers are defined in the root and being passed in to the module.
There are also no resources in the root module at all, so nothing is trying to use the default provider *from the root module*.
I'm not using `configuration_alias` at all, I'll look in to that now.

Comment: @MarkoE: What should I set `terraform.required_providers.aws.configuration_aliases` to in the `terraform` configuration of each module? Making it a list with a single item as either: `aws`, `<AWS_REGION>`, or `aws.<AWS_REGION>` all emits the `Invalid provider local name` error.

Comment: Ok, and have you actually defined the `provider` block in any of the child modules? I think this also might help: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/providers#passing-providers-explicitly.

Comment: @MarkoE: Can you be specific about what the "`provider` block" is? I'm trying to set `provider = aws.<AWS_REGION>` in the body of every `resource` block, mentioned in one of my scenarios, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario #4 actually solved the problem: explicitly specifying a per-AWS-region provider for every resource in every per-AWS-region module made the providers work for the first time. I was just thrown off by all of the planned destruction events that started showing up.

***(See the [Terraform Discuss thread](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/terraform-catch-22-lack-of-default-provider-causes-error-default-provider-breaks-per-region-providers/62078) for more detailed information and discussion with the Terraform developers.)***